# Cannot change default Phonegap icon

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Im using Phonegap Build to package my app. I have gone in to the "settings" section and uploaded the app icon:

[image]

I then rebuild. However, when I go to the public page and download the .apk, I still get the default Phonegap icon. When I look in /assets/www/res/icon/android/ in the .apk package, I see the standard Phonegap icons. Any ideas why it's ignoring my uploaded icon?

Comment: I got the same problem and I solved it here. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330448/how-can-i-change-the-default-icon-of-cordova-phonegap-when-doing-remote-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cordova/PhoneGAp project when created will have some default images along with in the platform related folders. There will be multiple files based on the device screen size.

They are the default icons and you can replace them.

If you use Eclipse ADT, it has inbuilt option of generating multiple size files for an image which gets added to the project automatically.

Comment: Im using Phonegap Build which is supposed to package in the app with the different platforms. But it's ignoring my icon. I will have to do it manually. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't manually upload an icon in the setting section of Phonegap Build, as the apk will use the icon specified in the `config.xml` file.

The Phonegap Build UI has been since then updated to show:
`Your application's details are bound to the config.xml file in your application package. To edit these details, change that file and push it back up to us.`